# In Memoriam: Louis Gossett Jr

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[One of the great character actors](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001283/) of the past half century has passes away.  While he had many memorable roles, my favorite was as one of the three main characters in *Enemy Mine*.

As I was composing this, trying to find the right clip, my boss heard the video playing in his office next door and came over to ask what I was watching.  I told him, and we reminisced about the film, which he had first seen (dubbed) as a student in the Soviet Union.

Although it's not my favorite film, Gossett's performance in *An Officer and a Gentleman* was impressive and universally acclaimed.

Comment: He was also known as Gerak in SG-1: https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Gerak

Comment: Also, a bit speculative, but I always saw some connections between "Enemy Mine" and the classic TNG episode "The Enemy" which has almost exactly the same plot. In any case, he was a great actor, RIP.